# Magento2, remove gift options from cart page

Tags: magento2, blocks, shopping-cart

I made below in my theme, but new xml does not remove the git option block.

```
/app/design/frontend/Mytheme/themename/Magento_GiftMessage/Magento_GiftMessage/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml
```

and

```
/app/design/frontend/Mytheme/themename/Magento_GiftMessage/Magento_GiftMessage/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml
```

the xml is:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.order.actions.gift_options" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use

```
/app/design/frontend/Mytheme/themename/Magento_GiftMessage/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml
```

and

```
/app/design/frontend/Mytheme/themename/Magento_GiftMessage/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml
```

use `Magento_GiftMessage` only once not twice and don't need `view/frontend`.

Comment: Does it matter which one?

Comment: You can use `checkout_cart_index.xml`.

Comment: I removed the cache and deployed again, but still I see git options in cart page...So weird

Comment: have you set proper `theme`?

Comment: Yes my theme works as I did other customizations, but this one :/

Comment: have you used `/app/design/frontend/Mytheme/themename/Magento_GiftMessage/layout/` this?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need this functionallity at all, another option would be to disable the module output:

- Just go to `Stores` > `Configuration` > `Advanced` > `Advanced`
- Search for `Magento_GiftMessage`
- Disable it and clear cache

Comment: Note to people, this sadly was removed in `2.3`  - The ability to adjust modules within the Admin Backend. Has to be done via the CLI now.

Answer (score 2):

A much better approach is simply to disable this feature rather than edit code or disable the module output.

1. On the Admin sidebar, tap Stores. Then under Settings, choose Configuration.
2. In the panel on the left, under Sales, choose Sales.
3. Expand  the Gift Options section.
4. If necessary, clear the Use system value checkbox. Then, do the following:
   a.  If the setting is for a specific store view, choose the store view where the configuration applies.
   b.  When prompted, tap OK to continue.
5. Set the Gift Message options according to your preference:
   Allow Gift Messages on Order Level
   Allow Gift Messages for Order Items
6. When complete, tap Save Config.

For more details see the Magento User Guide:
http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/checkout-gift-options.html

Answer (score 2):

For Magento 2.4.0:

In app/design/frontend/YourVendor/yourtheme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.giftcardaccount" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.gift_options" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.gift_options" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.bundle.actions.gift_options" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.grouped.actions.gift_options" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.configurable.actions.gift_options" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.gift-card.actions.gift_options" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.order.actions.gift_options" remove="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have added this as a comment on Fabian Schmengler's correct answer, but I don't have the reputation to do it.  If a moderator can move this that would be great.

---

Another reason why this really needs to be done via the admin instead of via XML is because removing the block will cause a Javascript error.  More information can be seen on here, on the Magento issues tracker.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6983